# PHP PDO can't connect to localhost

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, psql

PHP: using PHP 5.3.10 on an ubuntu vm through Vagrant
DB: Postgres 9.3.2.0

I can easily connect to a remote DB; however, when I try to connect to a local dev DB I have, I get an error

```
new PDO("pgsql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1;user=user1;password=tester;port=5432");
```

> [Mon Jun 08 21:37:15 2015] [error] [client 10.0.2.2] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused\n\tIs the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting\n\tTCP/IP connections on port 5432?' in /lib/Db.inc:28\nStack trace:\n#0 /lib/Db.inc(28): PDO->__construct('pgsql:dbname=te...')\n#1 /www/page1.php(9): Db->__construct('postgres://test...')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /lib/Db.inc on line 28

I know this isn't a connection issue since my local db is up and running fine

```
psql postgres://user1:tester@127.0.0.1/testdb
```

Comment: connection refused = nothing listening on that ip and/or port number, or a firewall is actively denying the connection by sending an icmp destination unreachable.

Comment: Try removing the port or else try to port 3306

Comment: @Szenis PostgreSQL, not MySQL ;)

Comment: Can you psql into the server? Can you see it running in top / ps / netstat? This is sounding more like a config, and if so a serverfault question.

Comment: I can psql into the server just fine

Comment: `sudo netstat -nlp|grep 5432`?

Answer (score 1):

I do running on Fedora 23 and after changing `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf` from `ident` to `md5` I was not able to connect with `psql postgres://user1:tester@127.0.0.1/testdb`. Finally found out that selinux blocks the connection.

Quick fix is to edit `/etc/selinux/config` to `disabled` and reboot. But checking how to work with selinux and ports would be better solution.

Comment: I don't know why but if i spend maximally 1 hour facing a problem in my linux, then I have to think this certainly has something to do with SELinux system and I'm always right about it. Anyways I don't think this is best practice to disable SELinux especially in an environment where it exists. In case of fedora, just write 'setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db on', that way you are telling selinux to accept your apache implementation to connect the "distant" (local) database.